# DateTime.ParseExact() Exception

Tags: c#

I'm trying to make the following function work but I'm getting an exception:

```
Date = "30/06/2015";
Time = "02:50 p.m";
DateTime FechaLeida = DateTime.ParseExact(Date + ' ' + Time, "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

As far as I know the syntax is correct, so I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: What's the exception?

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
var Date="30/06/2015"; 
var Time= "02:50 pm"; 
DateTime FechaLeida = DateTime.ParseExact(Date + ' ' + Time, "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Changes:

1. Remove the `.` in `p.m`
2. Change the time parser to be `hh:mm` instead of `HH:mm`